# Return the value of a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, return, countdown

**Code:**

```
var n = 360; // 6 min of waiting after blocked
function countDown() {
    n--;
    if (n > 0) {
        setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
    }
    $("span#waitcount").html(document.createTextNode(n));
}

var count = 50; // Count of tokens when reached 0 block the page
var counter = document.getElementById('counter');

var clickDisabled = false;
$('.slotMachineButton').click(function() {
    if (clickDisabled)
        return;
    setTimeout(function() {
        count--;
        counter.innerHTML = count;
        if (count === 0) {

            $.blockUI({message: '<h1>Thank you for Playing!!!<br>Please wait for 6 munites to be able to play again.</h1>'});
            setTimeout(function() {
                $.unblockUI({
                    onUnblock: function() {
                        alert('Game has been resumed!!!');
                    }
                });
            }, 10000);
            setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
        }
    });
    clickDisabled = true;
    setTimeout(function() {
        clickDisabled = false;
    }, 3000);
}
```

**Goal:**

- When the token count reaches 0 return it to original value to start again another count, because whenever the count reaches zero it goes -1 and keeps going.
- When 6 min waiting is over start another waiting, I dont know if I got the code right for this part but please do check.

Comment: Well for one you are missing a parentheses. Also if you want to repeat a function call every 1000 milliseconds, you should use setInterval, not a recursive call to setTimeout. Also you don't specify where in the code you reset the values of count and n. Finally, if your only question is "please do check", it does not belong on StackOverflow.

Comment: Instead of decrementing a counter it would be better to save the time stamp of when the timer started (via `Date.now()`) and then subtract that time from the current time and then see if more than 360 seconds have passed. [Timers in JS](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) are not precise, you are guaranteed that your callback will fire after a **minimum** period of time; it could take longer for the timer to fire the callback.

Comment: The `count--` and the `n--` shout go at the end of the functions and must be reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your code and you don't follow the suggestions in the the comments, then to this:

```
        var n = 360, // 6 min of waiting after blocked
            count = 50, // Count of tokens when reached 0 block the page
            counter = document.getElementById('counter'),            
            clickDisabled = false;

        function countDown(){
            if(n > 0){
                setTimeout(countDown, 1000);
            } else {
                n = 360;
                clickDisabled = false
            }
            $("span#waitcount").html(document.createTextNode(n));
            n--;
        }

        $('.slotMachineButton').click(function () {
            if (clickDisabled) {
                return;
            }
            setTimeout(function () {
                counter.innerHTML = count;
                if (count === 0) {
                    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Thank you for Playing!!!<br>Please wait or 6 munites to be able to play again.</h1>' });
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $.unblockUI({
                            onUnblock: function () {
                                clickDisabled = true;
                                alert('Game has been resumed!!!');                                    
                                setTimeout(countDown, 10);
                            }
                        });
                    }, 1000);
                    count = 50;
                }
                count--;
            });
            clickDisabled = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                clickDisabled = false;
            }, 100);
        });
```

Bud you should realy look for a diffrent aproach. I changed the timer values for testing.